# Find out who is running the process on the remote machine

Tags: vb.net, process, vb.net-2010

I am trying to get a list of processes running on remote machine and the username running them. So far I've got:

```
Dim ps As System.Diagnostics.Process
For Each ps In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses("myserver")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ps.ProcessName)
Next
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code ? Do you have permission to access myserver ?

Comment: the code runs fine! i just need to know which attribute gives me the username who runs the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to get permissions for using System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcess(string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757711/problem-using-system-diagnostics-process-getprocessstring) - this might be a better way to do it. It is in C# I can translate it if you want.

```
''' using System.Management;  
' don't forget! in VS you may have to add a new reference to this DLL
 Dim op As New ConnectionOptions()
 op.Username = "REMOTE_USER"
 op.Password = "REMOTE_PASSWORD"

Dim sc As New ManagementScope("\\REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME\root\cimv2", op)

Dim query As New ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

 Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(sc, query)
 Dim result As ManagementObjectCollection = searcher.[Get]()

 For Each obj As ManagementObject In result
     If obj("Caption") IsNot Nothing Then
         Console.Write(obj("Caption").ToString() & vbTab)
     End If
     If obj("CommandLine") IsNot Nothing Then
         Console.WriteLine(obj("CommandLine").ToString())
         End If
Next



 Public Function GetProcessOwner(processId As Integer) As String
    Dim query As String = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " & processId
         Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
     Dim processList As ManagementObjectCollection = searcher.[Get]()

     For Each obj As ManagementObject In processList
         Dim argList As String() = New String() {String.Empty, String.Empty}
         Dim returnVal As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList))
         If returnVal = 0 Then
        ' return DOMAIN\user
             Return argList(1) & "\" & argList(0)
         End If
     Next

     Return "NO OWNER"
 End Function
```